# Applying class name when parent element has a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a document that by default has the class `slide--current` applied to the first element on page load as you can see in my code below. Each time one of the button options at the bottom of my code is clicked, the `slide--current` class gets applied either to the previous `slide` element or the next one depending on which option is chosen.

What I'm trying to accomplish in either Javascript or jQuery is, when the parent of `text-block`, which is `slide`, has the `slide--current` class, add a class to the `text-block` element. I'm wanting to add a class to fade in and out that particular div when its parent is the current slide.

```
<div class="slide slide--current">
      <h2 class="title title--centered title--modifier">Slide 1</h2>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>Slide 1 text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h2 class="title title--centered title--modifier">Slide 2</h2>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>Slide 2 text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <h2 class="title title--centered title--modifier">Slide 3</h2>
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>Slide 3 text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

<nav class="actions">
  <button class="btn btn--trigger btn--prev">Previous</button>
  <button class="btn btn--trigger btn--next">Next</button>
</nav>
```

Update: 
Main Javascript code is below, but uses third party plugins to help with the animation, but should be irrelevant to what I want to accomplish.

```
(function() {


  Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for (var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}

  var isModernBrowser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') ||
                        navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') ||
                        navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;

  if (isModernBrowser) {
    var chromeAlert = document.getElementsByClassName('browser-alert');
    chromeAlert.remove();
  }

  var bodyEl = document.body;

  var Slide = function(el) {
      this.el = el;
      this.txt = new Scale(this.el.querySelector('.title'));
    },

    Slideshow = function(el) {
      this.el = el;
      this.current = 0;
      this.slides = [];
      var self = this;

      [].slice.call(this.el.querySelectorAll('.slide')).forEach(function(slide) {
        self.slides.push(new Slide(slide));
      });
      this.slidesTotal = this.slides.length;
      this.effect = this.el.getAttribute('data-effect');
    };
  Slideshow.prototype._navigate = function(direction) {
    if (this.isAnimating) {
      return false;
    }
    this.isAnimating = true;
    var self = this,
      currentSlide = this.slides[this.current];
    this.current = direction === 'next' ? (this.current < this.slidesTotal - 1 ? this.current + 1 : 0) : (this.current = this.current > 0 ? this.current - 1 : this.slidesTotal - 1);
    var nextSlide = this.slides[this.current];
    var checkEndCnt = 0,
      checkEnd = function() {
        ++checkEndCnt;
        if (checkEndCnt === 2) {
          currentSlide.el.classList.remove('slide--current');
          nextSlide.el.classList.add('slide--current');
          self.isAnimating = false;
        }
      };

    currentSlide.txt.hide(this.effect, function() {
      currentSlide.el.style.opacity = 0;
      checkEnd();
    });

    nextSlide.txt.hide();
    nextSlide.el.style.opacity = 1;

    nextSlide.txt.show(this.effect, function() {
      checkEnd();
    });
  };
  Slideshow.prototype.next = function() {
    this._navigate('next');
  };
  Slideshow.prototype.prev = function() {
    this._navigate('prev');
  };


  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.content')).forEach(function(el, pos) {
    var slideshow = new Slideshow(el.querySelector('.slideshow'));
    el.querySelector('.actions').firstElementChild.addEventListener('click', function() {
      slideshow.prev();
    });
    el.querySelector('.actions').lastElementChild.addEventListener('click', function() {
      slideshow.next();
    });

  });

    // bezier function: https://github.com/arian/cubic-bezier
  function bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2, epsilon) {
    var curveX = function(t) {
      var v = 1 - t;
      return 3 * v * v * t * x1 + 3 * v * t * t * x2 + t * t * t;
    };
    var curveY = function(t) {
      var v = 1 - t;
      return 3 * v * v * t * y1 + 3 * v * t * t * y2 + t * t * t;
    };
    var derivativeCurveX = function(t) {
      var v = 1 - t;
      return 3 * (2 * (t - 1) * t + v * v) * x1 + 3 * (-t * t * t + 2 * v * t) * x2;
    };
    return function(t) {
      var x = t,
        t0, t1, t2, x2, d2, i;
      // First try a few iterations of Newton's method -- normally very fast.
      for (t2 = x, i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        x2 = curveX(t2) - x;
        if (Math.abs(x2) < epsilon) return curveY(t2);
        d2 = derivativeCurveX(t2);
        if (Math.abs(d2) < 1e-6) break;
        t2 = t2 - x2 / d2;
      }
      t0 = 0, t1 = 1, t2 = x;
      if (t2 < t0) return curveY(t0);
      if (t2 > t1) return curveY(t1);
      // Fallback to the bisection method for reliability.
      while (t0 < t1) {
        x2 = curveX(t2);
        if (Math.abs(x2 - x) < epsilon) return curveY(t2);
        if (x > x2) t0 = t2;
        else t1 = t2;
        t2 = (t1 - t0) * .5 + t0;
      }
      // Failure
      return curveY(t2);
    };
  };
  var duration = 500,
    epsilon = (1000 / 60 / duration) / 4,
    easing1 = bezier(0.1, 1, 0.9, 1, epsilon);
  anime.easings['myCustomEasing'] = function(t) {
    return easing1(t);
  };


})();
```

Comment: Can't you just write a CSS rule that handles it without adding a class?

Comment: What is not working? Please give us also your JavaScript code, to see what is not working.

Comment: Please add the relevant JS code.

Comment: @epascarello I'm wanting to apply the class as the user clicks on one of the given buttons, and then to the next element, and next element after.

Comment: @alpham8 code added

Comment: If you have the element on which you're applying `slide--current`, just find the child element that has `text-block` and add whatever you want to it. You're already using `querySelector`, so you know how to use that... Note that @epascarello's point is that you could just as easily achieve the same with a CSS rule like `.slide--current > .text-block`.